# Retrieve users with common interests based off interestID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with the following columns: {userID, interestID}. I'm having a hard time with wrapping my head around retrieving the top 20 users that have common interestIDs based off the userID I pass in. I would like to also retrieve the count of the common interest for each common interest user in the response.

Any ideas? Thanks a ton!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the `CREATE TABLE` statements of the relevant tables, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements, the results you want with these sample data, the query you have so far and an exact explanation what's not working with that query and what that query should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select t.userid, count(*) as interests_in_common
from t join
     t tx
     on t.interestid = tx.interestid and tx.userid = $x
group by t.userid
order by count(*) desc
limit 20;
```